# ANTLR Array Translation

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, antlr, antlr4

I’m writing a code translator in ANTLR v4 and C#.  My input can be considered to be C, except for multidimensional arrays which are defined as columns and rows and I’m outputting to C.

Basically I’m trying to convert this:

int abc[2][] = {1, 2, …… }

To

int abc[][2] = {1, 2, …… }

and then swap the indexes used in its statements.

Currently I’ve a typical ANTLR listener (as in the book) and using the C grammar file.  I’m overriding EnterDeclarationSpecifier and starting to walk the tokens i.e. I’m creating a visitor within the listener to walk the declaration.  Is there a simpler way to do this ? Whilst I’m about to get the declaration working, if I follow the same approach for statements it seems too complicated.